# Read integers from file and save two integers per index in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have research about what I am trying to accomplish. This is my code, and here the main function is to read a file.txt which has integers separated by white spaces and they will be read one by one. However, I want to know... How Can I stored the integers inside a ArrayList, But in each index of the ArrayList there will be two integers instead of one, as usual?

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ReadFile {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] arr = readFile("address.txt");
            System.out.println("The memory block generated is:");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        }
            // access this method in FIFO
            public static int[] readFile(String file) { // this main method

                try { // try and catch

                File f = new File(file);
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                Scanner r = new Scanner(f); // read the file with scanner 
                int count = 0; // count for the integers

                while(r.hasNextInt()) { //  while keep reading 
                    count++;
                    r.nextInt();

                }

                int[] array = new int[count];

                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                Scanner readAgain = new Scanner(f); // read again

                ArrayList<ArrayObjects> blockMem = new ArrayList<>(); // array size * we can use dynamic array

                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                // i want to iterate and save them 
                }

                return array;

            } catch(Exception fnf) {
                System.out.println(fnf.getMessage() + "The file could not be open, try again");
                System.exit(0);
            }
                return null;

            } // method closed  
   }`
```

Comment: Create an `ArrayList` which can hold an `int[]` array, ie `ArrayList<int[]> data = new ArrayList<>(25);`, then simply create a new `int[]` array for each row, add your values to the `int[]` array and then add that to the `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class with two integers.

```
class TwoIntegers{
    int one,two;
    TwoIntegers(int data1,int data2){
        one = data1;
        two = data2;
    }
}
```

Now create an Arraylist of objects of type TwoIntegers

```
ArrayList<TwoIntegers> blockMem = new ArrayList<TwoIntegers>();
//now you can iterate and insert integers you need
blockMem.add(new TwoIntegers(1,2));
blockMem.add(new TwoIntegers(3,4));
```